# Error in CloneFunctioninto() LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-3.0

I'm trying to copy the CFG in function into a new function to do some operations with old one.
I used CloneFunctionInto by the following code

```
      std::vector<Type*> ArgTypes;
      ValueToValueMapTy VMap;
      FunctionType *FTy = FunctionType::get(F.getFunctionType()->getReturnType(), ArgTypes, F.getFunctionType()->isVarArg());
      Function *NewF = Function::Create(FTy, F.getLinkage(), F.getName());
      SmallVector<ReturnInst*, 8> Returns; 
       CloneFunctionInto(NewF, (Function*) &F, VMap, false, Returns, "_", 0, 0);
```

The error I have got after printing each basic block in the new and old functions :

While deleting: i32 %

Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  %cmp1_ = icmp sgt i32 %4, 20

opt: Value.cpp:75: virtual llvm::Value::~Value(): Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"' failed.

```
0  opt             0x0000000000fc7fe2

1  opt             0x0000000000fc8473

2  libpthread.so.0 0x00007f2b28876cb0

3  libc.so.6       0x00007f2b27ac8425 gsignal + 53

4  libc.so.6       0x00007f2b27acbb8b abort + 379

5  libc.so.6       0x00007f2b27ac10ee

6  libc.so.6       0x00007f2b27ac1192

7  opt             0x0000000000f7cd7d

8  opt             0x0000000000ee3c52

9  opt             0x0000000000f5bddf llvm::LLVMContextImpl::~LLVMContextImpl() + 1999

10 opt             0x0000000000f5ad1c

11 opt             0x0000000000fb9d69 llvm::llvm_shutdown() + 41

12 opt             0x00000000005285b3 main + 7251

13 libc.so.6       0x00007f2b27ab376d __libc_start_main + 237

14 opt             0x0000000000521f91
```

Stack dump:

```
0.  Program arguments: opt -load ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/Blocks.so -blocks
```

Aborted (core dumped)

To clarify more: it gives me the correct basic blocks with its correct successors, but it also doesn't work well because of this error

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're copying the arguments over appropriately. Take a look at the `llvm::CloneModule` function (in `lib/Transforms/Utils/CloneModule.cpp`) to see how to use `CloneFunction` correctly.